# PHP/MySQL - how to push additional elements into array in the "while" loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm pulling the information from an mySQL database, but I need to add additional fields that are not in the database.

The code below works fine, until one of the commented options is enabled:

```
$sth =  mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql); 
while($r3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    //array_push($r3, 'str_close'=>$est_close_time);
    //$r3['str_close']=>$est_close_time;
    $row_v3_data[]=$r3;
}
```

Once enabled, the php shows "Error 500"

Comment: dosen't your values get replaced in the `$row_v3_data[]` array ???

Comment: If an error 500 is thrown, there is something written to the server's error log most of the time. Can you search for that message and add it to the question?

Comment: Eki did you checked the answer?

Comment: The question is resolved, thank you all ! I just needed to use "=" instead of "=>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add the other data to `$r3` before adding it to the array

```
$sth =  mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql); 
while($r3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $r3['str_close'] = $est_close_time;
    $row_v3_data[]   = $r3;
}
```

> This assumes `$est_close_time` actually exists before using it

Comment: A oneliner variation on this answer which replaces `$r3['str_close'] = $est_close_time;
    $row_v3_data[]   = $r3;`. is `$row_v3_data[]   = array('str_close' => $est_close_time, $r3)` or for PHP 5.4+ `$row_v3_data[] = ['str_close' => $est_close_time, $r3]; `

Comment: Thank you that was the idea, I just have not think of using "=" instead of "=>" . This works perfectly !

Comment: The surprising part is it is being added to the end of the array $r3, but it works regardless.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a key and an element to an associative array at the same time. the format is just:

```
$r3['str_close'] = $est_close_time;
```

no need for an explicit push